# .NET WinForms printing API: Error handling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, exception

We have a WinForms application which has printing capabilities. However, our application suffered from crashes when our users tried to print, e.g. if printer configuration was broken. I managed to reduce the crashes, but still get a crash occasionally. For some reason, I haven't found a resource explaining how to properly do error handling with the printing API, so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's what we are doing now to prevent crashing: First, we have a `SafePrint()`method which basically does the following:

```
  public static void SafePrint(PrintDocument printDocument, IWin32Window ownerWindow)
  {
     try
     {
        printDocument.Print();
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
        ShowErrorDialog(ownerWindow, exception);
     }
  }
```

Second, we have a `CheckPrinterSettings()` method which accesses all kinds of properties on the `PrinterSettings`, catches exceptions if they happen to occur, and shows an error dialog in that case. We use that method in all our implementations of the `BeginPrint` callback like so:

```
  private void m_printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
  {
     Application.DoEvents();

     if (!Printing.CheckPrinterSettings(m_printDocument, this))
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
     }
...
```

The `CheckPrinterSettings()` method basically looks like this (and is of course to be considered a hack due to lack of information on proper error handing):

```
  public static bool CheckPrinterSettings(PrintDocument printDocument, IWin32Window ownerWindow)
  {
     var printerSettings = printDocument.PrinterSettings;
     if (printerSettings.IsValid)
        return true;

     try
     {
        // let's try to raise an exception
        var dummyBool = printerSettings.CanDuplex;
        dummyBool = printerSettings.Collate;
        dummyBool = printerSettings.IsDefaultPrinter;
        dummyBool = printerSettings.IsPlotter;
        dummyBool = printerSettings.SupportsColor;

        // too bad - let's show a generic error dialog
        MyTaskDialog.ShowError(ownerWindow, "Printing problems");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // let's show an error dialog with the (hopefully helpful) exception message
        MyTaskDialog.ShowError(ownerWindow, "Printing problems", ex.Message);
     }
     return false;
  }
```

However, as I said, we are still missing exceptions for some reason. Here's an example of a stack trace:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed.
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal(String printer)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal()
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(PageSettings pageSettings)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
    at System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl.ComputePreview()
    at System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl.CalculatePageInfo()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
```

Since our application does not even appear in the stacktrace, I have no idea on where it had been raised or how to catch it (note that this is a print preview).

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is there any documentation on how to properly do error handling with the .NET WinForms printing API, be it actual printing or previewing the print?
2. Any concrete hints on what we are missing?

Comment: There are no installed printers. You could use the [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the Spooler service state. If it is "Running", query all the installed printers and, if the returned collection is empty, notify and quit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm looking for more general advice (the above was an example for the exceptions we still see, the main purpose being to show that the stack trace does not contain any references to our code)...

Comment: There's no special error handling model for printing. You Try and you Catch, being aware that most of the time the printing process is out of your hands (Spooler->Driver). What you can do, before trying to print/preview anything: check the Spooler and the existence/status of a Printer/Job through WMI (with the limitations the System printing model imposes). The exception you posted, was just suggesting you are after some higher hierarchy in error handling, while still lacking in the basics (checking whether a printer is installed or the default/selected one capabilities fit your needs).

Comment: Ok, thanks - maybe I was expecting too much from that API (after all, a well-designed API would not make any user re-implement stuff like the checks you are suggesting, would it?)... However, "you try and you catch" is not possible for the exception I posted (as far as I can see), since our application is not even in the stack trace, so where to put the try-catch?

Despite that: Is there any documentation on the checks to be performed for a reasonable implementation of printing support, or do I really have to figure all of this out by means of trial and error?

Comment: .NET support for Form Printing is not great, but you'll get used to it. It's better if you use a Print Server (see: [System.Printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing(v=vs.110).aspx)). When you have those fail-safe checks I suggested in place, you should have very few exceptions that bounce back. Also check [InvalidPrinterException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.invalidprinterexception(v=vs.110).aspx). BTW, try printing with Photoshop after you have stopped your Spooler service ;)

Comment: Considering the given stack trace, it seems you are not handling the exception because `PrintPreviewControl` is calling `Print()` for you. That's also the reason why nothing from your own code appears on the stack trace. You should try not to let `PrintPreviewControl` do the printing, and call your `SafePrint()` method yourself :)